# D8045: cannot compile C file 'serialcommands.c' with the /clr option

Tags: .net, c++-cli, clr

I am getting compiler error D8045. cannot compile C file 'serialcommands.c' with the /clr option.

This file is a C library that has been written to talk over a serial port to a TI processor.  The task that I need to do is wrap this library with a CLR wrapper (there will be additional questions posted to stackoverflow concerning marshalling data back and forth if you want some more easy points from CLI questions.)

I just want to use this C library from my CLR wrapper.  I went to 
Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Compile with Common Language runtime support = No Common Language Runtime support

Is this the correct way to do this? Will I experience nasty weird bugs later or are other things that I need to do to use this?

Comment: as a follow up, I am now a year out from using this solution and never have experienced any problems as a result of using this solution.  No "wierdness" as I feared.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes.  You need to compile any C objects without /CLR, since the clr only understands classes and objects.

You can still use them from your C++/CLI project, wrapped inside of your "ref class" objects.  This is a normal way of wrapping a C api in .NET objects.

Comment: Note: This can be done "per file" not just per project, not sure that was clear from question/answer here on first reading.

Comment: This might help someone else out in the future.  I added a new .c file to an existing project with both C++/CLI and C files, and had this error.  In that case it seems that you must change the setting for new files added or they will pick up the settings for the project.  It took me a bit to figure out why I was seeing this problem for only one new files.  The setting is under C++/General.

Comment: Adding on to reply from user645280: more than _can_ be configured per file; this _must_ be configured at the file level; not the project level ... assuming one is in fact trying to build a CLR assembly (using C++/CLI).