# Getting error D8045 "cannot compile C file <file> with /clr option" even after turning off CLR option

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015, clr

This is in Visual Studio 2015.

I have a native C library that I'm using from my .NET Visual C++ code.  I'm aware that I have to change the "Common Language Runtime Support" option to "No Common Language Runtime Support" on the property page for each .c file, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880413/d8045-cannot-compile-c-file-serialcommands-c-with-the-clr-option).  However, even after I have turned that option off, I am still receiving error D8045 when I attempt to compile those files.

Is this a known issue in VS2015, or am I missing something?

Comment: That is the correct way to do it.  Standard reason to still get the error is forgetting to make this setting change for all configurations and all platforms.  The two combo-boxes at the top of the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cleared up on its own eventually.  I had restarted Visual Studio a few times and it kept happening, which is why I asked this question.  I guess some cache somewhere wasn't being updated or got corrupt or something.